# Getting my AVAudio player to work

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to use `AVAudioPlayer` to play an mp3. Here is the code that I have:

```
- (void) playClip {
NSString *mp3File = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inFavor" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3File] error:NULL];
[avPlayer play];
}
```

the name of the file that I'm referencing is "inFavor.mp3"

I'm a bit new to Objective-C so I'm not exactly sure why this isn't working. I'm using Xcode 5.

Comment: Have you verified that `mp3File` isn't `nil`? And make use of the `error` parameter so you can log the problem.

Comment: When there are so many questions involving AVAudioPlayer, what is so special about your question? -1

Comment: Just new to this and looking for help. My intention isn't to add to the clutter. What might seem obvious (or like a bad question) to someone experienced might seem normal to someone new. It can be a little intimidating on SO because for every person who answers a question there's someone telling you it's a stupid question. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the AVAudioPlayer a property of the class so that it is not released when the function goes out of scope.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer* avPlayer;
```

Then initialize with

```
self.avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3File] error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code, you need to check the error. paste the log you are getting in error

```
NSError *error;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inFavor" 
                                              ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* avPlayer = 
  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                         error:&error];
if (error) {
   NSLog(@"failed playing error: %@", error);
}else{
//avPlayer.delegate = self;
[avPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: on the line that reads:
    avPlayer.delegate = self;
it's giving me a (yellow) error message saying "assigning to id <AVAudioplayerDeligate> from incompatible type RJViewController *const_strong